# How Can I create a two-dimensional character array in Groovy/Grails

Tags: arrays, grails, groovy

I need to read in data and create a two-dimensional array character array of my input data.

Can you show me how to do this?

I am a grails/groovy extreme newbie.

Thanks,

Doug

Comment: What does your data look like and where will it come from?

Comment: It's very likely this question has nothing to do with Grails and more likely "I don't know how to program and I wanna make a website." or "I've only programmed for school and now I wanna be a web developer." You'll probably wanna pick up and work through Grails in Action or Getting Started with Groovy & Grails before moving much further.

Answer (score 2):

The same as in Java: `char[][]`. For example:

```
def chars = new char[5][5];
```